# get content from website and put content in disk drive

Tags: php

im trying to get an exe file from site web and put it in disk drive here is my code

```
@file_put_contents("C:\program.exe" ,       @file_get_contents("http://localhost/program.exe"));
```

some help please ?

Comment: Try taking off the two '@' symbols and see if you're getting any errors.

Comment: tip: On Windows, always use forward slashes in your PHP-side path stuff. PHP will auto-convert for you, saving you any escaping headaches.

Comment: @MetoMe: How would removing the `@` fix the issue?  The `@` just supress errors.

Comment: Rocket .. I was thinking the same thing. Maybe @MetoMe is saying that it simply revealed what the problem was? Perhaps he could be persuaded to share his findings ...

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `copy()`?

```
copy("http://localhost/program.exe","C:/program.exe");
```

Note that the cause was probably the unescaped backslash - I've used a forward slash here because Windows will silently convert it.

Comment: yes works too but whene i use shell_exec("start C:\program.exe"); it does not work php still sleeping and in the task manager i found the process runing

Comment: Again, the unescaped backslash is your problem. Try using two backslashes instead of one, or (again) use a forward slash and let Windows take care of it.

Comment: no result with shell_exec("start C:/program.exe"); still in the task manager and not runing !

Comment: yes @kolink and in the task manager it is runing with its memory but in the interface not runing whene i kill it (process) the php end to sleep so the php run it but block it perhaps